# Image might be corrupt after saving with FileOutputStream

Tags: android, fileoutputstream

So, i managed to download a file and saved successfully using FileOutputStream, i can see the image if i choose it via file manager but the thumbnail is not displayed also that image is not appear on gallery. I don't know if it corrupted or not since i can see the image when i choose it. So what's my fault?

This is the code:

```
AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
client.get(url, new AsyncHttpResponseHandler(){
    @Override
    public void onStart() {}

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] response) {
        try {
            FileOutputStream stream = new FileOutputStream(file);
            stream.write(response);
            stream.flush();
            stream.close();
            subscriber.onNext(file);
            subscriber.onCompleted();
        }catch (Exception e){
            subscriber.onError(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, byte[] errorResponse, Throwable e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        subscriber.onError(e);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, my friend just told me we should scan manually using [MediaScannerConnection](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaScannerConnection.html). My bad.